# How to conditionally select a character from two strings, based upon another string

Tags: python, substitution

I have 2 files: fileA is composed of 1 row  and file B is 2 rows.

#### fileA (1 row):

```
*****s**e**********************************************q*
```

#### fileB (2 rows):

- Row 1 is the subject
- Row 2 is the query

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

I need to produce an output file, where if the fileA string contains an `s` or `*`, the subject character at the corresponding index position, will be written to the output file. If there is a `q` or `e` the query character will be written to the output file.

```
Output:
AAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABA
```

my code:

```
ff = open("filea.txt")
gg = open("fileb.txt")
file_as_list = ff.readline()
file_as_last = gg.readlines()
query = file_as_last[0]
subject = file_as_last[1]
for i in file_as_list:
    z = -1
    while z <= len(file_as_list):
        if i == "*":
            f = open('output.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
            f.write(subject[z])
            z += 1
        elif i == "s":
            f = open('output.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
            f.write(subject[z])
            z += 1
        elif i == "e":
            f = open('output.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
            f.write(query[z])
            z += 1
        elif i == "q":
            f = open('output.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
            f.write(query[z])
            z += 1
    break
```

the things work more or less but not properly: I have always that the loop works only for the first statement and produce an output that is just a copy of the subject

Comment: Are the rest of the strings (the `*` positions) garunteed to match between the subject and query strings?  If not, which should be used to generate the output string?

Comment: yes, there is a perfect correlation and size length between query subject and file A

Comment: Yes 1 row for files and 2 rows for fileb

Comment: I just have 2 rows in file B with the 2 lines of characters. but if you think that would be easier I can put the names (subject, query) in the beginning of the strings

Comment: i ve just modified the strings in the example to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

- `with open` is used, so all files will be automatically closed
- convert each `string` into `list`, then`.strip` to remove `\n` & `\r`
- load the `lists` into a `pandas.DataFrame`
- `pandas.DataFrame.apply` with `axis=1`, for row wise operations

  - `np.where` to return the correct value
  - write `out`, to a `list`, and convert it into a `str`
- write `out`, to the `output.txt` file

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('fileA.txt', 'r') as filA:
    with open('fileB.txt', 'r') as filB:
        with open('output.txt', 'w', newline='\n') as output:
            fil_a = filA.readline()
            fil_b = filB.readlines()
            sub = [x for x in fil_b[0].strip()]
            que = [x for x in fil_b[1].strip()]
            line = [x for x in fil_a.strip()]
            df = pd.DataFrame({'A': line, 'sub': sub, 'que': que})
            df['out'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(np.where(x[0] in ['*', 's'], x[1], x[2])), axis=1)
            out = df.out.to_list()
            out = ''.join(x for x in out)
            output.write(out)
```